# How to load Parse PHP Classses in a simple module Drupal?

Tags: api, drupal, parse-platform, push, drupal-modules

I tried to use the Parse.com PHP SDK inside a (simple !) Drupal module to send Push notification, but Drupal don't load Parse SDK Classes. I've got PHP error :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ParseClient' not found
```

My files are :

```
push.module
push.info
parse_sdk/autoload.php
parse_sdk/ (and all files from https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk)
```

And in the file push.module :

```
use Parse\ParseClient;
require_once('parse_sdk/autoload.php');
ParseClient::initialize( $app_id, $rest_key, $master_key );
```

What's wrong with my code ??? Thanks for your help.

Actually it's working with REST API, but I can't get it with PHP SDK. I even tried to insert "files[] = parse_sdk/src/Parse/ParsePush.php" in push.info, wihtout success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this my answer :

```
require_once('parse_sdk/autoload.php');
\Parse\ParseClient::initialize( $app_id, $rest_key, $master_key );
```

Juste add "\Parse\" and it's work ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Jim 007 
This saved my 10 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Download `PARSE_PHP_SDK` from [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk)
2. Unzip it to folder  `.../root/parse_sdk/`
3. Create a php file in `.../root/` (for ex. `.../root/example.php`)
4. Write it in the php file:

```php
<?php
namespace Parse;
require_once('parse_sdk/autoload.php');
$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/push';
$app_id = 'YOUR_app_id';
$rest_key = 'YOUR_rest_key ';
$master_key = 'YOUR_master_key ';
ParseClient::initialize( $app_id, $rest_key, $master_key );
//YOUR OTHER CODE
?>
```